# Get `ps` to Show Process Not Attached to Terminal With Flags

Tags: bash, macos, shell, command-line, system-administration

Playing with the behavior of `ps -elf` and `ps aux`, I notice that `ps aux` tends to list more processes.

Reading the man page, I suspect the reason why `ps aux` would have more entries is that `x` in `aux` will also grab processes that aren't attached to any terminal.

Is there a way to provide command line flags to `ps` to also include those non attached processes? I notice that there is one to specify a `tty` or terminal but can't seem to find a flag that would also grab the unattached processes.

I have also tried the following but they seem to be invalid syntax:
`ps -elfx` and `ps -elf x`.

For reference, I am running this on Mac OSX and believe there maybe inconsistencies with the linux counterpart.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You might be better off asking this on [unix.se].

Comment: There are "UNIX style" and "BSD style" options, and you can't mix them. `ps aux` is "BSD style", `ps -e` is "UNIX style". Both should list all processes.  The `-l` and `-f` are UNIX options for output formatting.  Type `man ps` to read more.